# How to implement an editable UITableView, similar to Safari Bookmarks?

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I am trying to implement a list that works very much like the Bookmarks view in Mobile Safari.  When you click Edit, you get the following:

[image]

From this screen, you can delete an item and change its attributes (via the DisclosureIndicator on the right).  I followed Xamarin's [tutorial](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/tutorials/Working_with_Tables_and_Cells/Part_4_-_Editing), but I couldn't figure out exactly how to add the DisclosureIndicator, while the table is in edit mode.  I'll take the solution either in ObjC or C#.

Am I missing something simple here?

Answer (score 1):

In iOS this is done by means of the following methods:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return NO;
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}

- (void) setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing: editing animated: animated];
    [self.tableView setEditing:editing animated:animated];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
             //delete rows
    }
}
```

The disclosure indicator is a cell accessory. You can set it in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

}
```

Comment: I might be missing something, but the moment I put the UITableView into Editing mode, the DisclosureIndicator disappears.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator;
```

in GetCell method